# Badges page question

Tags: support, badges

Why does the [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) page say

*Here's a list of all the badges...*

and then list very few of "all the badges"?

... and does anyone know where I can see a list of all the badges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) tab in the top right which shows the topic badges.

Comment: Yes I just saw that.

Answer (score 0):

My Badges tab shows all the badges...