# Answers posted to a migrated question post-migration are not migrated

Tags: bug, specific-question, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Answers posted to a migrated question post-migration remain visible and unlocked on the original site.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19208/answers-posted-to-a-migrated-question-post-migration-remain-visible-and-unlocked)

When answering a question that is a candidate for being migrated; if you post an answer in the 'magical minute' after the question is migrated, your answer is not migrated.

#### Original Question:

**Stack Overflow** - [Badges Page Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849590/badges-page-question/) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849590/badges-page-question/1849602#1849602) (Posted in the magical minute after it was migrated)

#### Migrated Question:

**Meta** - [Badges Page Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31893/badges-page-question) *sans* my answer.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19208/answers-posted-to-a-migrated-question-post-migration-remain-visible-and-unlocked

Comment: Yet another edge (or even corner) case it doesn't seem worth fixing. Just transfer your question manually.

Comment: @ChrisF It's not my question, it's my answer.

Comment: Thanks Shog9, I searched but didn't find that. Voted to close as duplicate.

Comment: Fair enough - it's actually a slightly different aspect of the same underlying problem, so you could conceivably suggest auto-migration of late answers as an alternate solution to those I propose.